# Find docs with ISODate fields in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection which has fields that are sometimes ISODate and sometimes Date. I need to convert the Date fields to ISODate but I am not sure how to filter the docs. I am open to either doing so in a query or in the code. I am not finding a type of ISODate to check the instanceof/typeof the field. Suggestions?

```
Item.find(function(err, docs) {
  docs.forEach(function(d) {
    if(d.updated instanceof ISODate) // That type does not exist mongoose/mongo Types.
      ...
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of `docs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator. It inspects and matches based on the BSON type of the property, which for a `Date` is type 9:

```
Item.find({ "updated": { "$type": 9} },function(err, docs) {
```

Of course if they are not actually dates but "strings", then use the appropriate BSON type for that:

```
// Find strings in updated.
Item.find({ "updated": { "$type": 2} },function(err, docs) {
```

Comment: Excellent. How would I convert the string date to ISODate?

Comment: @Yashua depends on what the string looks like. Generally `new Date()` will do. There is no such thing as an `ISODate`, it's just a representation in the mongodb shell. If you have other questions then please [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).